# Maximal independent set and minimum dominating set

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to build an example of a simple undirected graph that will satisfy the following claim:

***Of all possible maximal independent sets of some graph $G = (V,E)$, not a single one can be also a minimum dominating set.***

We know that every maximal independent set is a dominating set. In order to construct such example we should have a minimum dominating set that is not in the list of all possible maximal independent sets of some graph $G = (V,E)$ and that has a cardinality smaller than any set in the list of all possible maximal independent sets. Is it possible to find such graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the following tree:

[image: Graph]

The only minimum dominating set (of size 2) is not an independent set at all.